# I can't open terminal in Visual Studio Code

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

[image]

The '+' button to open terminal in my visual studio code does not work.
Also, the default profile selection button does not work.

The only thing I changed was from "launch.json" to "externalConsole: false->true".
Even if I try to restore it to its original state, it remains the same. I tried reinstalling the VSCode, deleted the "setting.json" file, and recreated it. But... :(

Originally, I was using git bash as a standard, but you can see it. There is only "JavaScript Debug Terminal" left.

Please help me, friends.

My "launch.json" file

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "gcc.exe - 활성 파일 빌드 및 디버그",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "C:/MinGW/bin",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "gdb에 자동 서식 지정 사용",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe 활성 파일 빌드"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Windows, hence commands are for Windows, but you can definitely find the alternative commands for your OS in case you happen to use an OS other than Windows.

Open your `settings.json` file(`File -> preferences -> Settings` or `Ctrl+,`) and look for the configuration `terminal.integrated.profiles.windows`  (newer recommended setting). If you see`terminal.integrated.shell.windows` then it is the older deprecated setting.

If you are on linux or Mac, then look for the `terminal.integrated.profiles.linux` or `terminal.integrated.profiles.osx`. If you don't find these, then perhaps you don't have any terminal profiles setup and you need to set it up.

Setting up a terminal profile is quite easy.

In your `settings.json` file you need to create a new setting with key `terminal.integrated.profiles.windows` (or `terminal.integrated.profiles.linux` or `terminal.integrated.profiles.osx` based on your system). Start typing the above key and once VSCode shows the suggestion hit Enter(Return). If you don't see any suggestion for auto-complete try hitting `Ctrl+Space`. Your settings will auto-populate against the above key and will look something like following:

```json
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash"
        }
    }
```

In addition to above you can also setup a default terminal profile. Include the below setting(here Git Bash has been configured as the default terminal profile) :

```json
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash"
```

You can always use the `Ctrl+Space` to force VScode to provide you with the possible values.

Few handy links :
To [create a new profile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles).
To go to the [command pallette(**Ctrl+Shift+P** on windows)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)

Comment: Thank you for the really good advice. However, when set in my window environment, the + button and the select default terminal button are still disabled. I tried reinstalling the VScode just in case, but it remains the same.
It is the same that only the javascript debug terminal remains in the drop-down box.
I thought it could be a bug, so I did report it.

Answer (score 1):

I am on macOS with an issue like this as well. My terminal instantly closes when I try to open it and I have not found a good solution. The best I can do it just reinstall VScode.